# How to rollback to MainActivity when using SherlockFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

My class use `extends SherlockFragment` lets say `News class` and when my proccess is finish on `onPostExecute` block, I have finished ListView displays all the data well.

If I click on one of the list, all I want is to call a `Detail class` by bringing all the data that has been retrieved from the server.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new NewsDetail()); 
        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

How do when the **Back** button is clicked I want to go back to the `Class` before?

Comment: `NewDetail` is a Fragment?

Comment: you need to add the fragment to the back stack

Comment: @Raghunandan how to do that? I already use `Back Button` handler in my MainActivity to catch `App Exit Dialog` , and when the back button is clicked instantly bring up a dialog application to terminate the application (Back Button Handler)